# AWS DescribeSnapshots requires several requests to return results

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using the Java AWS SDK to query for EC2 snapshots matching a specific filter (just two tags). My testing shows that the first query is always returning 0 results, but getNextToken() returns a value, and so continuing to loop through requests and providing the previously returned nextToken eventually returns the results. Sometimes I will loop through 5-8 times all with 0 snapshots returned but with a nextToken available before I get a result that has the results I'm looking for.

The max results field I've set is 1000, and my understanding from their documentation is that getNextToken should only return a result if the number of matching results is > the value set on max results.

The query is definitely correct and using the AWS CLI returns the expected results. Has anyone ever encountered this?

Comment: Care to post your code including the filter?

Comment: Try `--debug` with aws-cli.  Does it also have to go through multiple iterations in order to actually fetch the full results (but you don't realize it, since it's automatic and hidden)?  If you have a large number of snapshots, it is possible that the service has limits on the amount of unmatched scanning it can do without returning and asking you to come back with another token.